# How to edit multiple cells in Excel at once?

Tags: excel

I want to edit multiple cells in Excel at once.

Example: Put a certain string in front of the content of each cell.

How can I achieve this? Maybe with regular expressions and 'serach & replace'?

Comment: Excel's Find&Replace doesn't support regex unfortunately. A quick method might be to use `CONCATENATE` (or the equivalent `&` concatenator).

Comment: Do you know in advance which cells will change when you edit one? You could use the inbuilt `Events ` of the `Worksheet` to track changes in your cell, compare the start and finish values of the cell and affix the alteration to another range that you specify

Comment: Do you accept a VBA solution?

Answer (score 4):

I need to do this regularly and the least messy way I have found is copying into Sublime Text and editing there as it supports editing multiple lines simultaniously.

[Link to Sublime Text Website](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find some add-in, e.g. [RegEx Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/index/new-excel-add-in-regex-find-replace) or work with some existing UDFs, e.g. [here](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Relying on "a certain string" to imply this is always or usually the same string, then an 'appearances only' solution might possibly be of interest. ie format the cells to include the relevant text. Either `"certain text "@` or `"certain text "#`:

[image: SO18631571 example]